# WPF - Connect EventSetter to an ICommand

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm, mouseevent, icommand

I'm looking for a solution where I double click on a DataGridRow that calls a method in my ViewModel with an ICommand.

I have this code for my DataGrid's DataGridRow style:

```
<DataGrid.Resources>
    <Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
        <EventSetter Event="MouseDoubleClick"
                     Handler="DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick" />
    </Style>
</DataGrid.Resources>
```

This works, but...
I need to have the method `DataGridRow_MouseDoubleClick` in the XAML's code-behind. Then in that method I need to call the method in my ViewModel.
I would like to bypass the code-behind and directly call the method in the ViewModel with an ICommand.

I found this code which was elegant but, calls the method whereever I (left) double click on the DataGrid.

```
<DataGrid>
    <DataGrid.InputBindings>
        <MouseBinding Gesture="LeftDoubleClick"
                      Command="{Binding MyCallback}" />
    </DataGrid.InputBindings>-->
</DataGrid>
```

I can only allow double click on a DataGridRow.

Any suggestions?

/BR
Steffe

Comment: What you want is a behavior.  An `EventToCommandBehavior`.  It is something that has been implemented in many places..  Just google it and you'll find many.  I think there is one in the MS Xaml Behaviors NuGet Package  https://github.com/Microsoft/XamlBehaviorsWpf.   I know there's one in the commercial UI toolkit I use.  and there are plenty of examples

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could replace the event handler with an attached behaviour that executes the command:

```
public static class DataGridRowExtensions
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty MouseDoubleClickCommandProperty =
        DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "MouseDoubleClickCommand",
            typeof(ICommand),
            typeof(DataGridRowExtensions),
            new FrameworkPropertyMetadata(default(ICommand), new PropertyChangedCallback(OnSet))
    );

    public static ICommand GetMouseDoubleClickCommand(DataGridRow target) =>
        (ICommand)target.GetValue(MouseDoubleClickCommandProperty);

    public static void SetMouseDoubleClickCommand(DataGridRow target, ICommand value) =>
        target.SetValue(MouseDoubleClickCommandProperty, value);

    private static void OnSet(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)d;
        row.MouseDoubleClick += Row_MouseDoubleClick;
    }

    private static void Row_MouseDoubleClick(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        DataGridRow row = (DataGridRow)sender;
        ICommand command = GetMouseDoubleClickCommand(row);
        if (command != null)
            command.Execute(default);
    }
}
```

**XAML:**

```
<Style TargetType="{x:Type DataGridRow}">
    <Setter Property="local:DataGridRowExtensions.MouseDoubleClickCommand"
            Value="{Binding DataContext.MyCallback,
                RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=DataGrid}}" />
</Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, install the Nuget package mentioned below in your project.

```
Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf
```

Then add the following reference to the relevant xaml field.

```
xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/xaml/behaviors"
```

As the next step, you can apply the double click function as follows.

```
<i:Interaction.Triggers>
     <i:EventTrigger EventName="MouseDoubleClick">
          <i:InvokeCommandAction Command="{Binding MyCallback}"/>
     </i:EventTrigger>
</i:Interaction.Triggers>
```

Comment: I actually already have the `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Wpf` package installed :)
But I cannot use you code example in the style.
I need the double click to happen only on the `DataGridRow` and the only way I know how to access the DataGridRow is in the style of the DataGridRow.
The example you gave is not applicable in the style what I know.
Any suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is it you want to do? Why do you only want the DataGridRow to be double clicked?

Comment: When double clicking on a DataGridRow we display a window with more detailed information than in the DataGridRow.
If I add a double click event on the DataGrid, I can click everywhere in the DataGrid to trig the event. Then I have to implement checks that I have clicked on a DataGridRow and nothing else and then display the Window with details information.