# Which is the difference between to use a dependecy property as command and to use a custom routed event?

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a user control with a datagrid. I would like to notify to the main view that a user doble click in an intem of this datagrid. I would like to notify the doble clicked item too.

For that, the first solution that I thought it was to use a custom routed event, how I could see in the [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/desktop/wpf/events/how-to-create-a-custom-routed-event?view=netdesktop-6.0).

But I have seen that another option it is to define a dependency property that is a ICommand. This it would be the code:

```
void RaiseItemDobleClickEvent(object sender, MouseButtonEventArgs e)
     {
       ItemDobleClickCommand.Execute(null);
     }
    
     public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandProperty = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("ItemDobleClickCommand", typeof(ICommand), typeof(Window011UC1));
     // Declare a get accessor method.
     public static ICommand GetItemDobleClickCommand(UIElement target) => (ICommand)target.GetValue(CommandProperty);
     // Declare a set accessor method.
     public static void SetItemDobleClickCommand(UIElement target, ICommand value) => target.SetValue(CommandProperty, value);
    
    
     public ICommand ItemDobleClickCommand
     {
       get { return (ICommand)GetValue(CommandProperty); }
       set { SetValue(CommandProperty, value); }
     }
    
     public static readonly DependencyProperty CommandParameterProperty = DependencyProperty.Register("ItemDobleClickCommandParameter", typeof(object), typeof(Window011UC1));
     public object ItemDobleClickCommandParameter
     {
       get { return (object)GetValue(CommandParameterProperty); }
       set { SetValue(CommandParameterProperty, value); }
     }
   }
 }
```

Then in the main view I could use it in this way:

```
<Label Content="DoubleClick UC2" MouseDoubleClick="{Binding RaiseItemDobleClickEvent}"/>
```

I see that it is two ways to do the same, but I don't know which are the differences, when to use one solution or another or the advantages or disadvantages of each one.

So when to use a depency property as command and when to use a routed event?

Thanks.

Comment: For your use case, I think using a normal event handler would be most suitable if it’s just for notification, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/msdn-magazine/2008/september/advanced-wpf-understanding-routed-events-and-commands-in-wpf

Answer (score 1):

Well, en event is an event and the other approach is commonly referred to as an [attached behaviour](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/28959/Introduction-to-Attached-Behaviors-in-WPF) and it's frequently used in MVVM apps.

You cannot bind an event to a property like this though:

```
MouseDoubleClick="{Binding RaiseItemDobleClickEvent}"
```

What you do is that you define a custom dependency property and register a callback that invokes the command. You'll find an example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71311318/wpf-connect-eventsetter-to-an-icommand/71323312#71323312).

The XAML would look something like this:

```
<Label ... local:YourClass.MouseDoubleClickCommand="{Binding YourViewModelCommand}" />
```

Comment: it is a good example, thanks. But which is the difference or when to use an event and when to use a attached behavior? Sometimes it seems there are many ways to do the same thing and I can't find a clear documentation about the differences. Thanks so much.

Comment: Welcome to the world of software development. There are almost always several ways to solve an issue. In this case, when you want to bind to a command property of a view model, you won't benfit from creating a custom event.